# How to prove $\lim_{n\to \infty}{\frac{a_n-1}{\log(a_n)}}=1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

How to prove when $$\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n=1$$
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{a_n-1}{\log(a_n)} =1$$

Can I just use the following to prove

$$\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{x-1}{\log(x)} =1?$$

It there a way to use [Stolz–Cesàro theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem) to prove the above? I am curious to know.

Comment: What information is given about {$a_n$}?

Comment: Yes, that is the Heine characterization of limit: $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=L$ iff for every sequence $a_n$ such that $\lim_na_n=a$ we have that $\lim_nf(a_n)=L$.

Comment: Stolz-Cesaro Thm requires information about the sequence $(a_n)$.

Comment: You need to assume that $a_n\neq 1$ and then use the standard limit $(x-1)/\log x\to 1$ as $x\to 1$.

Comment: If $a_n\neq1$, then L'Hospital rule applies to $\lim_{x\rightarrow1}\frac{x-1}{\log(x)}$ will do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $a_n \to 1$ there exists $N$ such that for all $n \geqslant N$ we have $-\epsilon < a_n-1 < \epsilon$.

For $0 \leqslant x < 1$ we have the inequalities

$$\frac{x}{1+x} \leqslant \log(1+x) \leqslant x , \, x \leqslant -\log(1-x) \leqslant \frac{x}{1-x} $$

If $1 \leqslant a_n < 1+\epsilon$, taking $x = a_n-1$ and using the first inequality we get

$$\frac{a_n-1}{a_n} \leqslant \log a_n \leqslant a_n-1\\\implies 0 \leqslant \frac{a_n-1}{\log a_n}-1 \leqslant a_n-1 < \epsilon$$

If $1-\epsilon < a_n < 1$, taking $x = 1 - a_n$ and using the second inequality we get

$$ 1- a_n\leqslant -\log a_n \leqslant \frac{1-a_n}{a_n}\\\implies -\epsilon < a_n-1  \leqslant \frac{a_n-1}{\log a_n}-1 \leqslant 0$$

Thus, for all $n \geqslant N$ we have $-\epsilon <  \frac{a_n-1}{\log a_n}-1 < \epsilon$ proving that

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}  \frac{a_n-1}{\log a_n} = 1$$